# Split a Master Workbook into Multiple Workbooks in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code from a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bOFNsdHiPk&t=326s).

```vb
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()
    'Step 1 - Name your ranges and Copy sheet
    'Step 2 - Filter by Department and delete rows not applicable
    'Step 3 - Loop until the end of the list
    Dim Splitcode As Range
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")
    
    For Each cell In Splitcode
        Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("MasterData")
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I receive an error

> That name is already taken. Try a different one.

on

```
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
```

It seems like it copies the "Master" sheet in its entirety instead of going through the rest of the filtering/copying process because it makes a Master (2) & Master (3) sheet each time I hit run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message is because the code is trying to rename a sheet using a name which already exists. Your code is pretty much a "run once" method.

You can handle the error by first deleting any existing sheet.

```vb
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

    Dim Splitcode As Range, wb As Workbook, cell As Range, nm As String
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Sheets("Master")
    Set Splitcode = wsMaster.Range("Splitcode")
    
    For Each cell In Splitcode.Cells
        nm = cell.Value

        On Error Resume Next   'ignore error if no sheet with this name
        wb.Sheets(nm).Delete   'delete any existing sheet with this name
        On Error Goto 0        'stop ignoring errors

        wsMaster.Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        With wb.Worksheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            .Name = nm
            With .Range("MasterData")
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>" & nm, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
            .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End with
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking, I got yours to work! Much thanks!

Comment: @NantyNarking In that case you mark this answer as accepted.